# The zoom tool does not work in Pinta

Tags: zooming, pinta

The zoom tool does not work in Pinta. Holding Ctrl and scrolling does nothing. The buttons "Zoom in" and "Zoom out" have no effect. Nothing happens when I type in a zoom percentage.

Other than that the painting tools seem to work.

For me it started with Kubuntu 19.10 but Pinta has been unchanged for many Ubuntu releases ([the last change was in 2015 at the time of this question](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/p/pinta/pinta_1.6-2/changelog)) so it may happen with other versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this bug entry on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pinta/+bug/1464855) this has something to do with an illegal character in the Spanish translation. The issue has been fixed by a developer ([pull request #128 has been merged](https://github.com/PintaProject/Pinta/pull/128)) but Pinta has not been released since the issue was fixed so it remains open in the current Pinta 1.6.

An easy workaround is to bypass the language support. Open the file `/usr/bin/pinta` in a text editor and add a new line with the text `LANG=C` before the last line which starts with `exec`. The file must be saved with admin rights since it is a system file. Pinta will use English instead of the default language of your desktop but the zoom tool will work again.

If you don't want to change a system file or if you want to test the workaround before applying it on your system you can open a console and type `LANG=C pinta` and press enter. This has the same effect as the workaround described above but it is not permanent, i.e. it will only work until you close the instance of Pinta you just started.

Comment: Even though the issue is fixed in the upstream of Pinta, the Ubuntu package is not being updated regularly so I filed a bug for the zoom tool not working against Ubuntu's package of Pinta: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pinta/+bug/2016443

Answer (score 3):

Pinta 1.7 is available in the stable repository.
Zooming tool issue is fixed in this version.

Just run to add and install/update lastest pinta stable version.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pinta
```

Source : https://www.pinta-project.com/howto/installing-pinta

Comment: This is good news that Pinta 1.7 (which fixes the issue) is on its way. Still I would not recommend the use of PPA to the average user. Maybe a warning that the first command is adding a repository which is not from the Ubuntu official release would improve your answer.